# How to launch functions depending on screen size and stop others after resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to launch different functions depending on screen size after load, resize and scroll. To prevent effect of calculations in other functions I need to stop them.

Here if example with dummy functions from [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eqcxwddd/9/)
Here is example with real functions from [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eqcxwddd/6/) (it doesn't show html or css, just functions for your understanding)

If you look at console you will see that after first rezise first function runs, but when you get another window size breakpoint another function will run together with first one. the same with third function if you get third breakpoint. I want to stop function after window changed size to another breakpoint

here is my jquery:

```
function sticker1220() {  
  $(window).on("load resize scroll",function(){
    console.log('sticker1220');
    });
};

function sticker950() { 
  $(window).on("load resize scroll",function(){
    console.log('sticker950');
    });
};

function sticker320() { 
  $(window).on("load resize scroll",function(){
    console.log('sticker320');
    });
};

function checksize() {

  if ( $(window).width() > 1220 ) {
    sticker1220();
  } else if ( $(window).width() > 640 & $(window).width() < 1219 )  {
    sticker950();
  } else if ( $(window).width() < 639 ) {
    sticker320();
  }
};

checksize();
$(window).resize(function() {
checksize();
$('p').text($(window).width());
});
```

Comment: I probably wouldn't put those listeners in all three functions. I'd probably set them at the top level, and control their execution from common handlers. Otherwise, if one of those functions runs, you will have added the handlers/listeners within it, and if you need it to stop, you'd have to remove those handlers. But since you create no reference to them (and I don't see any removers in your code), how would you expect the functions to stop? Note that you can add all the handlers you want to a given event, they'll just all fire.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

I have abstracted the media queries into an object that can be iterated to find the applicable callback if one is available.

There is also now only on resize callback which is easier to manage as you don't need to run separate resize events which could lock up your ui thread. And the events will work properly if you change the screen resolution, whereas previously were binding a new resize event each time the screen resized.

If you need to make it faster you could change the resize event to a recursive timer using setTimeout.

```js
function checksize(mediaQueries) {
  return function(e) {
    const width = window.innerWidth
    $('p').text(width)
    const query = mediaQueries.find(x => {
      switch (true) {
        case !!x.min && !!x.max:
          return width >= x.min && width < x.max
        case !!x.min:
          return width >= x.min
        case !!x.max:
          return width <= x.max
        default:
          return false
      }
    })
    if (typeof query.cb === 'function') {
      return query.cb(e)
    }
  }
}

var atMedia = [
  {
    max: 639,
    cb: function(e) {
      console.log('sticker320')
    }
  },
  {
    min: 640,
    max: 1219,
    cb: function(e) {
      console.log('sticker950')
    }
  },
  {
    min: 1220,
    cb: function(e) {
      console.log('sticker1220')
    }
  }
]

$(window).resize(checksize(atMedia)).trigger('resize')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
```